# Running singularity container from Colab notebook?

Tags: google-colaboratory, singularity-container

I was able to install Singularity in Colab notebook. But the call to run container failed.

```
! singularity pull shub://singularityhub/hello-world
! ./hello-world_latest.sif
```

FATAL:   container creation failed: mount /proc/self/fd/3->/usr/local/var/singularity/mnt/session/rootfs error: while mounting image /proc/self/fd/3: failed to find loop device: could not attach image file to loop device: no loop devices available